# Eclipse.exe -Entry Point Not Found android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new android developer. When i run eclipse.exe the the following warning is shown 
Eclipse :eclipse.exe -Entry Point Not Found
The procedure entry point _JVM_LoadSystemLibrary@4 could not be located in the dynamic link library  jvm.dll 
what can i do now. please help me any one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure your JRE/JDK is properly installed. Check environment variables of your computer OS too.

Answer (score 0):

Download this file and install it **Systems (KB2999226)**

I've installed it on windows 7 for x64-based system and it worked!!!
the link is given bellow...

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49093